# generating strings from name and surname

Tags: java, string, random

I have a requirement to generate strings from names and surname. To give more detail: The generated string length can not exceed 11.

For the string "Leo Messi" I can directly generate "Leo Messi" but

For "Cristiano ronaldo" as you see the length exceeds 11, I should generate something like "C. Ronaldo", "Christiano R."

Another example "Diego Armando Maradona" I can generate "D. Maradona", "A. Maradona", "Diego A. M." and so on...

I must find a good algorithm to generate these kind of strings that doesn't exceeds length 11. What is your opinion. Is there any library that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Can you have duplicating names?

Comment: How is the user inputing their names? If you are using GUI could you just make a pop-up error message, saying to abreviate their names with enitial - last name or something?

Comment: @dave yes i can have

Comment: @Kalkrin there is nothing related to GUI here. I must generate these kind of string from the user input.

Comment: @jit You realize I'm trying to get you to add some details so people will actually answer your question and keep it from getting closed, right? FYI library recommendations are off topic for StackOverflow in addition to this being too broad.

Comment: you could use a regex to shorten the string and use random to pick the first or last name

Comment: How do you measure "good" in "a good algorithm"? The simplest is just truncate at the 11th character. Tell us why that simple solution would not suffice.

Comment: @tnw I dont have any rules for now beside the length 11. If i can find any library for this purpose, first off all i will use it and add my own rules if needed. I don't want to spend my time writing a code that already exists.

Comment: If you don't have any rules, then one way is as good as another. Just truncate.

Comment: @hatchet when you read the generated string, you should at least say "hmm name starts with character C and surname is Ronaldo". Of course the length 11 is not the only requirement.

Comment: The problem you have is that each culture may have the most significant part of the name in a different spot. Changing a given name of "Abdur Rahman" to "Abdur R." renders the the name virtually meaningless. But for an English name like "William James", changing that to "William J" is totally appropriate. To do this right, is not only non-trivial, I doubt there is a set of rules that would not make an innappropriate choice for some person's name.

Comment: @hatchet yes you hit a good point. I didnt know arabic names have this kind of meaningless but my culture is the same as "William J." example that you gave.

Comment: I would split the names and save them to an array. Use one of the array elements with substring to get the first character then add the first caracter string with the other element of the array.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would set this up with some simple if statements.

Some psuedocode:

If the whole string is less than 11 characters, leave it as is and print it like that.

If that doesn't work, see if you can print the first name, a space, and the abbreviated last name in less than 11 characters. (something like "Christiano R.")

If that doesn't work, see if you can print the abbreviated first name, a space, and the last name in less than 11 characters (something like "C. Ronaldo").

Else, abbreviate both names ("C. R.")

Obviously this won't work with a middle name but you get my point of how to set this up.

As for the actually coding, I'll let you have fun with that, but "string".substring(x,y) is something you'll probably use.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I am able to write all those things you mention but as i already told in my further comments; if there is something for this purpose i want to use it first, so if there are no any libraries like this I will do the exact same things you tell.

Comment: Well, nothing on the top of my head that I can think of for this situation, but it shouldn't be too intensive using built-in methods and such. Is this for a homework assignment? If so, I'm assuming your instructor wants you using native stuff. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

a simple algorithm can be

If the full name is more than 11 characters, get the shortest name and check if it has less characters that will allow you use initials of the other names otherwise use initials for all the names